# Warning when C++ globals are not explicitly initialized?

Tags: c++, clang++

Say I have a global (or namespace-scoped) variable like:

```
int *Pointer;
```

This is, of course, zero initialized, but is there a way in Clang (or with Clang's static analysis tools) to warn about `Pointer` not being explicitly initialized? I have searched and been unable to find anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could fairly easily write (and contribute) a [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) check to complain about that.

Comment: In case you haven't seen them ... List of clang diagnostics flags: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, I searched through the Diagnostics Reference page.

Comment: Is "no" a valid answer to this question? Because the answer is "no". It just feels too simple.

Comment: If the answer is no, then yes. That's valid.

Comment: @AndyG You'll have to find some fancy unicode characters to make that answer long enough.

Comment: @Yakk No! No! NO! NOOOOOOOOOO!

Comment: @Yakk: &zwj;&zwj;&zwj;&zwj;&zwj;

Comment: @AndyG Sadly, SO treats zero width spaces as whitespace despite UNICODE saying they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By standard there is no reason to warn about implicit initialization, it is not different from explicit.  If you're derivator enough, you may replace traditonal types with templates that would warn about it. But that defeats the goal to be lazy, right?

Or, even better, do not use naked pointers, aliasing pornography is not cool.